# How do I create a transparent textview on click at the bottom of the running screen?

Tags: android, screen, transparent, textview

How do I create a transparent textview on click at the bottom of the running screen?

Comment: Are you tring to create a textview when the onClick method of something else is triggered? Or do you want a textview and define it's own onClick method?

Comment: If you are trying to interpose a "transparent textview" on applications that are not yours, that is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean make the textview invisible and being able to turn it visible, you can use this attribute in your xml textview :

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

and then you can turn it visible with setvisibility().

now if you just want the background of your textview to be transparent, you have to define it's background color has #ffffffff

Comment: Defining #00000000 the background becames black. I would like to see the Android's desktop on the background of the text, is there a way?

Comment: My mistake, I think it must be better with F's instead of 0's. 
I'm not sure you can see the actual desktop with the apps and everything. Or I don't know how

Answer (score 4):

Defining `#00000000` the background, whereas the first 2 are it's alpha state (`Transparency`), and then the other 6 are RGB. Alpha is 00-FF.

Hope this helps!